AWS creadential provider using strings
Is there are way to directly provide aws credentials as strings to AWS CredentialProvider using aws JS SDK v3?
I am using the following code, and instead of using environment variables, I want to directly pass the credentials as string. Is there a way to do this?
   const client = new SFNClient({region:'us-east-1',
   credentials: fromEnv()});


credentials: { accessKeyId: '', secretAccessKey: '' },

Getting error "resolved credential object is not valid
